# Use Camel route to listen a topic

Tags: apache-camel, activemq-classic

When I send a message to the topic, why the processor get 10 exchanges? This is my code.

```
public class RouteTest extends RouteBuilder {
  public void configure() throws Exception {
    from("activemq:topic:Topic.ansyncMessage").process(new Processor() {
        public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
          System.out.println(exchange.getIn().getBody());
        }
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Please add your code into the question with the code tags rather than linking to a screenshot, people will be much more likely to help.

Comment: Because you probably have the program started like 10 times.

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo 'ansyc' -> 'async'